# Inserting values into the tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to insert values into the table that I created.

This is attributes and datatypes for my table.

```
CREATE TABLE DDR_Customer
(customer_name VARCHAR2(30),  
 customer_ID NUMBER(5), 
 city VARCHAR2(20), 
 street VARCHAR2(20),
 prov CHAR(2),
 postal_code VARCHAR2(6),
 phone_number VARCHAR2(15), 
 email VARCHAR2(50),
 credit_number VARCHAR2(20), 
 credit_type VARCHAR2(2), 
 credit_card_expiry VARCHAR2(15));
```

This is insert command that I'm trying.

```
VALUES ('Max Lu', 12345, 'Calgary', '9 Street', 'AB', 'L9L9L9', '403.892.8677', 'Jennalee@gmail.com', '4324 2424 2222 2222', 'AX', '10 Dec 19');
```

Also here are my constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE DDR_Customer
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CUS_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (customer_ID)
 MODIFY (customer_name CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME_NN NOT NULL )
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_PROV_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (prov, '|AB|BC|MB|NB|
     NL|NS|NT|NU|ON|PE|QC|SK|YT|'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(postal_code,'([A-Z][0-9]){3}[0-9][A-Z]){3}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_PHONE_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(phone_number,'[1-9]([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){4}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_EMAIL_UK UNIQUE (email)
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_NUM_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(credit_number,'[0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_TYPE_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (credit_type,'|MC|VS|AX|'));
```

It keep saying *unmatched parentheses in regular expression*

Comment: This works fine in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f96ac77349d8af080ef5909f14bd46f6.

Comment: I see an unmatched parenthesis in the constraint for postal code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - the regex is a string, so it's not evaluated during the table DDL. The error is raised when we try the insert statement, because - as DaveCosta points out - the regular expression used in SYS_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CK is not valid.

Comment: @APC I'm a little confused. How do I fix the problem then?

Comment: @APC I'm trying to enforce format like L9L9L9 -> where L is a letter and 9 is a digit.

Comment: @APC now it says, 'check constraint (CPRG250.SYS_CUSTOMER_PHONE_CK) violated '

Comment: @APC the phone number should be formated like 999.999.9999 where 9 is a digit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to enforce [postal] format like L9L9L9

So that is a regex of `'([A-Z][0-9]){3}'`.

> the phone number should be formated like 999.999.9999

Your regex is has a leading digit which you need to remove. The regex should be `'([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){4}'`

Once you've fixed that there's also a problem with PROV. I trimmed the pipes from that regex and now your insert statements inserts cleanly. [Here is a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a75db3/1).

Final (?) correct version:

```
 ALTER TABLE DDR_Customer
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CUS_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (customer_ID)
 MODIFY (customer_name CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME_NN NOT NULL )
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_PROV_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (prov, 'AB|BC|MB|NB|
     NL|NS|NT|NU|ON|PE|QC|SK|YT'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(postal_code,'([A-Z][0-9]){3}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_PHONE_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(phone_number,'([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){3}[.]([0-9]){4}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_EMAIL_UK UNIQUE (email)
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_NUM_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(credit_number,'[0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}'))
 ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_TYPE_CK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE (credit_type,'MC|VS|AX'));
```

Incidentally, I think the over use of regular expressions is a bad thing. They perform poorly compared to built-in SQL functions. For instance the check constraints on the character strings should be implemented as straightforward IN clauses:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT SYS_CUSTOMER_CARD_TYPE_CK CHECK (credit_type in ('MC','VS','AX'))
```

or even as foreign keys on lookup tables.

---

I'm a bit worried that your constraints start with SYS_. Why is that? They are user-defined constraints. I do hope it doesn't mean the table is owned by SYSTEM (or even worse SYS).